# There were x there have been

Tags: grammar, differences, syntactic-analysis

I was looking at the phrase "this road is very dangerous. There have been many accidents." And I was wondering what difference there is between this sentence and "there were many accidents."

I'm aware that "have been" is usually used for things that happened just now, but in that case the accidents could have happened at any time. I know that by using "have been" you could express that the action is still continued in the present while with "were" the action doesn't extend to the present, but to me it seems that both "have been" and "were" in that context have the exact same meaning.

Why is it grammatically correct to use "have been" in that phrase?

Comment: The use of past simple ('There were many accidents') indicates that that period is finished, closed. Thus 'Before the by-pass was opened, there were many accidents.' // 'There have been many accidents' strongly implies that this sorry state may well continue: there is no indicator of closure.

Comment: 'have/has been/ ' (i.e. present perfect) is sometimes called the indefinite past. In this case you are not specifying exactly when they occurred, but rather quantifying the number of accidents, and possibly indicating that the situation is still on-going.

Comment: It's grammatically correct to use either "have been" or "were". What you're actually asking about is the difference between them.